# Can I change the Raspbian boot without building a new image?

Tags: raspbian, boot

can I somehow turn off the default "console" when booting the Raspbian or at least change the logo into something else?

And most importantly, can I do this without recompiling the install image of Raspbian? is the logo stored somewhere I can change directly somehow?

Reason for asking: the users who are going to turn this thing on, on a daily basis shouldn't see all these technical details nor the logo if possible. Okay, the logo is okay, if I could just remove the console-logging.

If only there was some kinda "verbose off" unless key is pressed or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the amount of messages by adding "quiet" option to the /boot/cmdline.txt

And (theoretically) you may turn it off completely redirecting console to something invisible, when adding "console=tty10" to the same cmdline.txt file.

So, it may ends with:
...root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait console=tty10 quiet

Comment: console=/dev/null ? These messages will land in dmesg anyway

Comment: cool, going to try this when I get home.

Comment: what about the logo? is that easy to replace? not that I dont like the Raspberry logo, but I might do a more sci-fi version or something

Comment: The bootup logo, by default, is stored within the kernel image itself. In that case, you just need to recompile the kernel after configuring it to use a different logo.

Comment: okay, any newbie info on how to compile the kernel? never dared to try, but if possible on a Windows 7 64-bit, I will give it a try someday.